# How do you remove a document.addEventListener?

Tags: javascript

How do you remove a `document.addEventListener()`? In the fiddle below if you click the 'Dropdown Button' and then click outside the menu, multiple click events continue to fire (see console). I want to be able to hide the menu when clicking anywhere outside of it. I know I need to remove the event listener but I don't know how.

I've tried using a named function e.g.

```
document.addEventListener('click', myFunct);
```

However I can't pass any arguments to the parameters inside `myFunct` and I've also tried using `.bind()` with no success e.g.

```
document.addEventListener('click', myFunct(event, dropdownMenu));
document.addEventListener('click', myFunct.bind(event, dropdownMenu));
```

https://jsfiddle.net/shc3ek02/1/

```
let dropdownBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-trigger .button');

let initDropdown = function (event) {
    let dropdownMenu = event.target.closest('.dropdown');

    openDropdown(dropdownMenu);
    closeDropdown(dropdownMenu);
}

let openDropdown = function (dropdownMenu) {
    dropdownMenu.classList.add('is-active');
}

let myFunct = function(dropdownMenu) {
    if (!dropdownMenu.contains(event.target)) {
        dropdownMenu.classList.remove('is-active');
        console.log(event.target);
    }
}

let closeDropdown = function (dropdownMenu) {
    // works but fires multiple click events

    // document.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    //     if (!dropdownMenu.contains(event.target)) {
    //         dropdownMenu.classList.remove('is-active');
    //         console.log(event.target);
    //     }
    // });

    // this doesn't work
    document.addEventListener('click', myFunct(dropdownMenu));
}

dropdownBtn.forEach(function (button) {
    button.addEventListener('click', initDropdown);
});
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Keep in mind that you'll need to remove the same reference of the callback. [sample](https://jsfiddle.net/pdocmsne/)

Comment: `document.addEventListener('click', myFunct(dropdownMenu));` <= this looks like a bug.  You are immediately calling the `myFunct` method and binding the result (which is undefined) as the click handler.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand the answers provided and reading the docs on Mozilla didn't help so I've provided a new fiddle to help get my issue across better. If you click on the 'Dropdown button' then click outside of the menu, the click event still runs, I need document.addListener() event to stop, otherwise it keeps running (as in the example). I've tried putting the document.addListener() into a seprate function but now I can't access the menu var inside of newFunct why?

https://jsfiddle.net/ofqpcxk6/1/

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at `element.removeEventListener(event, function)`

(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener, https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_removeeventlistener.asp)